# Find out how Postman request is constructed and replicate in java

Tags: java, rest, postman

I am making a GET request using Postman. As part of the request, I selected `Authorization`, `Basic Auth` and then I filled in my username and password.

The request was successful. Now, I would like to replicate this in Java code.

In Java I tried this:

```
URL myURL = new URL(serviceURL);
HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)myURL.openConnection();
String userCredentials = "username:password";
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", userCredentials);
```

Although this seems to be similar to what Postman does, it doesn't work.

How can I replicate the above Postman request in Java?

Comment: Couldn't you just do some research how basic authentication works? Like reading: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-setting-up-and-using-basic-authentication--cms-24762

Comment: I don't know Postman, but it's easy to guess that it enables you to export the HTTP request it crafts. Check this output to know what data you should be setting. Also I think you should be setting a header field rather than a request property.

Comment: As the content in Tom's link points out, the header needs to base64 encode the username>password for basic authentication.

Answer (score 3):

There is a link on the Postman UI to generate code snippets for Java using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) or [Unirest](http://unirest.io), or for other languages and libraries.

**Step 1**
[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

Comment: So the part with `.addHeader("authorization", "Basic ems2djsSFSSF4madJDA==")`, how is this code generated? Is it the same in Postman and in another environment if I use he same username and password?

Comment: @octavian, you would supply the credentials to whichever library you're using based on your authentication scheme, for an example see http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/.  Alternatively, you can encode the credentials as base 64 yourself.  Java 8: java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((userCredentials).getBytes(‌​));

Answer (score 1):

As [this article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-setting-up-and-using-basic-authentication--cms-24762) (chapter "How Basic Authentication Works") points out, the header needs to base64 encode the username:password for basic authentication.

In Postman, you can see the encoded value in the headers' bulk edit:

[image]

You can lookup Java's own [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) utility class to do so.

**Edit**

If you either use Java's [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) or [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html) frameworks, you can use the solution underlined by [bn.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89339/bn) to quickly use a ready-made code template, instead of doing it "by hand".